# Unable to open a file in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I have written the following code in Verilog to open a file:

```
initial begin
clk=0;  i=0;done=0;
data = $fopen(":P\Desktop\image.txt", "r");
if (data== `NULL) begin
    $display("data_file handle was NULL");
    $finish;
end
final = $fopen(".txt","w");
end
```

I have specified the file location but, it returns an error:

```
WARNING: file PDesktopimage.txt could not opened
```

Any help how could I reoslve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your code, I get this message:

> Open failed on file ":PDesktopimage.txt". No such file or directory

Like your message, it does not have the backslash characters which are your directory separators.  However, my message does have the leading colon (`:`).

To get the backslashes, I escaped the backslashes using `\\`:

```
initial data = $fopen(":P\\Desktop\\image.txt", "r");
```

It is a good practice to avoid issues like this by placing the file to open into the current working directory before you run your simulation, then just open the filename without a path:

```
initial data = $fopen("image.txt", "r");
```

It is common to use a script to manage files and run the simulation.

Comment: A common solution is to use a symlink in the working directory pointing to the file in another location.